# Swift Equivalent of removeObjectsInRange:

Tags: objective-c, swift

Having a little trouble tracking down the Swift equivalent of:

```
//timeArray and locationArray are NSMutableArrays
NSRange removalRange = NSMakeRange(0, i);

[timeArray removeObjectsInRange:removalRange];
[locationArray removeObjectsInRange:removalRange];
```

I see that Swift does have a call in the API:  `typealias NSRange = _NSRange` but I haven't got past that part.  Any help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In addition to Antonio's answer, you can also just use the range operator:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.removeRange(1..<3)
// array is now [0, 3, 4, 5]
```

- The half-closed range operator (`1..<3`) includes 1, up to but not including 3 (so 1-2).
- A full range operator (`1...3`) includes 3 (so 1-3).

Comment: what does 1..<3 mean?  (in english) does it mean 1 to 1,2 or 3 depending how long the array is?

Comment: +1 that's a more compact version, recommended when the range is not reused

Comment: @Jeef: it's explained in [Range Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_126) - 1..<3 means from 1 (included) to 3 (not included), whereas 1...3 is inclusive

Comment: @Jeef Expanded answer. See also [Swift Range Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_126).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `removeRange` method of the swift arrays, which requires an instance of the `Range` struct to define the range:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let range = Range(start: 0, end: 1)
array.removeRange(range)
```

This code removes all array elements from index 0 (inclusive) up to index 1 (not inclusive)

**Swift 3**

As suggested by @bitsand, the above code is deprecated. It can be replaced with:

```
let range = 0..<1
array.removeSubrange(range)
```

or, more concisely:

```
array.removeSubrange(0..<1)
```

Comment: For better or worse init(start: end:) is being deprecated in Swift 3, and the warning presented by Xcode suggests using the '..<' operator instead. Some may miss the slightly more verbose but clearer style.