# Remove the cells below the selected one from the UITableView Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Here I am trying to remove the remaining objects after the selected one of an array when a particular row is selected from the UITableView.

Here is my sample array:

```
var myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
```

If I select `myArray[2]` the remaining elements after `"suhail"` should be deleted and the final array have to be `["rahul","rahib","suhail"]`.

Here is my try but it only remove one object:

```
var selectedIndex = indexPath.row
myArray.remove(at: selectedIndex+1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PiyushPatel this solution removes the selected item only..no need to remove the selected item. Remove the items after the selected item.

Comment: ok Just change your array to `var` from `let`

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913844/swift-equivalent-of-removeobjectsinrange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `let` to `var` for `myArray`

```
var myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
```

Use `removeSubrange(_:)` method to remove remaining item from the array

```
myArray.removeSubrange(indexPath.row..<myArray.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `myArray` was declared as a constant, you cannot modify it.

Change

```
let myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
```

to

```
var myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
```

and remove objects as normal.

```
var myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
let selectedIndex = 3
for index in selectedIndex...myArray.count-1 {
    myArray.removeLast()
}
print(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove

```
    var myArray = ["rahul","rahib","suhail","alex","siya"]
    print(myArray)

    let selectedIndex = 2
    myArray.removeSubrange(selectedIndex..<myArray.count)

    print(myArray)
```